# Reuse filenames in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to reuse the folder names in a particular directory while creating new files. Something like:

```
cat /home/sss/features/{month}/file-* > /home/sss/features_{month}.txt
```

I would replace {month} to be * in this command. Month can be any 12 months and not all months are always present. Final result should be concattenated files for each month:

```
/home/sss/features_JAN_2012.txt
/home/sss/features_MAR_2012.txt
/home/sss/features_NOV_2012.txt
```

Is it possible to do this somehow in linux?

Comment: it is of course possible to do this. have you attempted anything? does features only contain directories with month names? are there any other files matching `file-*` under each month?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
BASE=/home/sss/features

for f in `ls $BASE`; do
    cat `ls $BASE/$f` > $BASE_$f.txt
done
```

Comment: consider $() instead of the backtics... granted this could be attributed to taste...

Comment: Don't parse the output of `ls`, it's terribly broken, inefficient and useless: use globs instead.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with

```
for dirname in features/*
do 
    month="$(basename "$dirname")"
    cat "$dirname"/file-* > "features-$month-2012.txt"
done
```

Comment: We dont need to include the directory name in the month variable

Comment: @shaurya I have no clue what you mean by that. Have you even tried it?